How to write unit test case for angular code
I am trying to to write test case for my angular project. I am using angular version 16.
Below is my code.
In my code I am not getting component.appRuleList and component.appRuleOptions values in my test case. Getting like undefined both. How to get these values inside spec.ts file
app.component.ts:
public appRuleOptions:string[] = [];
public appRuleList:any[] = [];
public selectedName = 'test';
public private:Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

public ngOnInit(): void {
    this._store$
        .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy), select(applicationRows))
        .subscribe((userIdentificationPart: IApplicationRule) => {
            if (userIdentificationPart && userIdentificationPart.applicationRule) { 
                this.appRuleList = userIdentificationPart.applicationRule || [];
                this.appRuleOptions = userIdentificationPart.applicationRule.map(
                    (x: IApplicationMainRules) => this.selectedName + '/' + x.name,
                );
                
            }
        });
}
 

app.component.spec.ts:
 it('should subscribe to the store and update appRuleList and appRuleOptions on ngOnInit', () => {
const applicationRule = [
 
  {
      "name": "ui",
      "place": "usa"
  }
 ];

component.selectedName = 'test';
(component['_store$'].pipe as jasmine.Spy).and.returnValue(of(applicationRule));

component.ngOnInit();

fixture.detectChanges();


expect(component.appRuleList).toEqual(applicationRule); //Getting error
expect(component.appRuleOptions).toEqual([
  "power/testing" 
]);


});

I am expecting component.appRuleList and component.appRuleOptions values in the app.component.spec.ts file.

First add provideMockStore to the providers array of the testing module.
beforeEach(async () => {
  await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [provideMockStore()],
  }).compileComponents();
});

Then get this mock store to mock the returned values.
beforeEach(() => {
  store = TestBed.inject(MockStore);
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(App);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();
});

After getting the store and storing it, we can use the overrideSelector to configure the returned value.
  it('should subscribe to the store and update appRuleList and appRuleOptions on ngOnInit', fakeAsync(() => {
    const applicationRule = [
      {
        name: 'testing',
        place: 'usa',
      },
    ];

    component.selectedName = 'power';
    store.overrideSelector(applicationRows, {
      applicationRule,
    } as any);

    component.ngOnInit();
    flush();
    expect(component.appRuleList).toEqual(applicationRule); // Getting error
    expect(component.appRuleOptions).toEqual(['power/testing']);
  }));

Full Code:
import {
  TestBed,
  ComponentFixture,
  waitForAsync,
  fakeAsync,
  flush,
} from '@angular/core/testing';
import { MockStore, provideMockStore } from '@ngrx/store/testing';
import { AppState, App, selectBooks } from '../main';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let component: App;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<App>;
  let store: MockStore<AppState>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [provideMockStore()],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    store = TestBed.inject(MockStore);
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(App);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should subscribe to the store and update appRuleList and appRuleOptions on ngOnInit', fakeAsync(() => {
    const applicationRule = [
      {
        name: 'testing',
        place: 'usa',
      },
    ];

    component.selectedName = 'power';
    store.overrideSelector(applicationRows, {
      applicationRule,
    } as any);

    component.ngOnInit();
    flush();
    expect(component.appRuleList).toEqual(applicationRule); // Getting error
    expect(component.appRuleOptions).toEqual(['power/testing']);
  }));
});

Stackblitz Demo

What is the use of this? mockBooksSelector

Not working your concept. What is the use of mockBooksSelector and selectBooks ?

@Goutm I used an existing stackblitz which uses a book ngrx store, I updated my answer to mimic your scenario

Not working your concept

@Goutm no issues, sharing this stackblitz maybe it will help you

You are Great..Thank you so much

Can you answer 79275831 ?

@Goutm could you modify my stackblitz with your code, so that I can just  modify the test case without setting up everything, since not all of the code is provided for 79275831

What code you want?

@Goutm replicate the failing test case in stackblitz, I want the action, reducer, state configuration on the stackblitz

Everything is there, You can use in the stackblitz. I do not know how to use these in the stackblitz

You have any idea?
